# Differences between 2 dates in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a dataset and I need to compute the difference between a starting date and all the others dates in my column. So the final output will be a new column with the days between my starting date and all the others dates. Days must be integers

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should read the following two links: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [Provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Pasting your question title into the Search box yields [lots of useful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Differences+between+2+dates+in+python). You should have noticed that too when entering your question.

Answer (score 1):

So you can use the below reference code. You just need to iterate over your column data and assign it to from_date and to_date.

```
from datetime import datetime

from_date = "28-07-1997"
to_date = "09-04-2020"

d1 = datetime.strptime(from_date, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
d2 = datetime.strptime(to_date, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
ans = abs(d1-d2)
print(ans.days)
```